# jQuery toggle doesnt work

Tags: jquery, toggle

I need it so when you click on the other toggle, the box currently open closes, so its basically impossible for them to be both open at the same time?

But the toggle doesnt work.
https://jsfiddle.net/3gorcdra/1/

My JS Code look like this:

```
    $('.mix').next('.mix-content').hide();
$('.mix').click(function() {
    var el = $(this).next('.mix-content');
    var doit = (el.is(':visible')) ? el.slideUp() : ($('.mix-content').slideUp()) (el.slideDown());
});
```

I hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `find()` not `next()` since you are searching for `descendant`,

```
$('.mix').find('.mix-content').hide();
$('.mix').click(function() {
  var el = $(this).find('.mix-content');
  var doit = (el.is(':visible')) ? el.slideUp() : ($('.mix-content').slideUp(),el.slideDown());
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3gorcdra/8/)

Also your css for `mix-content` is having position absolute. I changed it, because the accordion like behavior cannot be achieved like that.

Comment: Thanks but the mix-content needs to be positioned absolute, because its no accordion.

Comment: @fr3d Yeah you can edit it as per your requirement. The issue that you have with your cide has been fixed. The problem is with `next`, and the usage of `ternary operator`. That has been fixed.